Seeking an algorithm or approach to compare values between two strings (.NET)
I have a problem with a piece of data as a string, and I have to check if the data exists between the stated ranges.
Note that if both ends are numbers, the comparison is not the usual number comparison. See the examples below:

Low-"9958", High-"99585" -> The following values are in range-> "9958", "99580", "99581", "99582", "99583", "99584", "99585".
Low-"30789", High-"310100" -> Values in range= "30789", "30790" to "310100"
Low-"81190", High-"81190ZZ" -> Values starting from "81190" to "81190A" and "81190AA". Then essentially all combinations of alphabets like "81190B", "81190C", "81190AB" to "81190ZZ".

I hope this helped. I am struggling to find if this kind of comparison is a known type of it and solutions that I can use already exist.
If I'm not doing a good job of explaining it properly, do not hesitate to let me know. I am happy to provide more examples
Edit
In case someone has a similar problem, I found RangeTree to store the high-low values and compare incoming data.

Have you made any thoughts on possible solution

Why is 9959 or 99580 not in the first example?

edited the question, as "99580" is in the first range. "9959" or a seemingly in-between number like 86344 is not in range.

@MaythamFahmi, I can generate the range, but was hoping to avoid re-inventing the wheel. The business owner is confident that this is a standard string comparison of some sort.

ok is this correct in the second example High-"3101"

standard string sorting seems like it would work. Have you tried?

@topsail, elaborate a bit more if possible.

Your question, as it currently stands provides some examples and asks us to infer a pattern from it AND provide an algorithm for that pattern. But it is you that should identify what pattern is that you want, otherwise it will be guesswork on our part, with you rejecting all our wrong guesses. So please describe the pattern you intend to implement in plain words. That will help us, and more importantly, you to understand what the task is. And once we and you understand what the task is, it will likely be a solvable issue.

Is "Low-"30789", High-"310100" -> Values in range= "30789", "30790" to "31000"" a typo? Why would the highest value be 31000 and not 310100?

This is a main program for a .NET console app that uses default .NET string comparison on your test data:
internal class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        var lo = "9958";
        var hi = "99585";
        var strings = new List<string>{ "9958", "99581", "99585" };
        CheckIt(lo, hi, strings);

        lo = "30789";
        hi = "310100";
        strings = new List<string>{ "30789", "30790", "31000" };
        CheckIt(lo, hi, strings);
        
        lo = "81190";
        hi = "81190ZZ";
        strings = new List<string>{ "81190", "81190A", "81190AA", "81190B", "81190C", "81190AB", "81190ZZ" };
        CheckIt(lo, hi, strings);
    }

    static void CheckIt(string lo, string hi, List<string> strings)
    {
        foreach(var s in strings)
        {
            Console.WriteLine($"{s} >= {lo} <= {hi}: {s.CompareTo(lo) >= 0 && s.CompareTo(hi) <= 0}");
        }
    }
}

All outputs are True. Of course you could write better test code and perhaps use a unit test approach but this is a simple example to get you started.
Note: although it may seem like a trivial topic, I hope sorting strings is a thing I hope all developers have pondered and explored for a few hours at some point in their learning. For instance, you should know why "1" could sort before "10" when sorted as a string, or whether "a" comes before "A". Once you understand this well enough, many other things start to makes sense (and other good questions comes to mind, such as does a with an accent in spanish come before a without an accent ... ?)

this is indeed it. thanks for taking time to explain. Compare string on range in SQL Server is another similar (not exact) explanation of this problem.

What about 995812 or 9958XY for the first range, 30789A or 30B for the second, 8119012 for the last? I'd guess there should be a check for no shorter than shorter bound, no longer than the longer one and, for differing lengths, "character class" of each position beyond the length of the shorter bound matches the one in the longer.
